# Undefined reference error in C++ program

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I'M parsing an XML file in C++ using RapidXML. I've made treeNode.h and treeNode.cpp files. I'm making a treeNode object to help me with the parsing. When I try to do this though, it's giving me an undefined reference error. The line of code which is giving me the error (I think) is the following line:

```
treeNode<xml_node<> > * tn = new treeNode<xml_node<> >(root_node);
```

If you're wondering where I got root_node from, it's defined in my main.cpp as the following:

```
xml_document<> doc;
doc.parse<0>(&buffer[0]);               
xml_node<> * root_node = doc.first_node();
```

The error message is this:

```
undefined reference to `treeNode<rapidxml::xml_node<char> >::treeNode(rapidxml::xml_node<char>*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

These are my three constructors in treeNode.h:

```
treeNode(T* element1);
treeNode(T* element1, T* parent1);
treeNode(T* element1, T* parent1, vector<treeNode<T>*> child1);
```

Any help with fixing this error would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: At a glance it looks all right. Are you sure you're linking `treeNode.o`, not just `main.o`? And is there any chance of a minimal complete example?

Comment: How would I link treeNode.o? I have included treeNode.h in my main.cpp and treeNode.cpp

Comment: is there a rapidxml library - if so u need -l<library> in your linker / compiler invoke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have implemented the `treeNode` methods in "treeNode.cpp".

In that case, they haven't been instantiated.

*All* your `treeNode` implementation needs to be in the `treeNode.h` header, so the compiler can instantiate the functions when they are used.
Otherwise, you will only have declarations, no definitions - because the compiler couldn't generate any - and you will get the same linking errors as if you didn't have any implementations at all.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented the treeNode methods/constructors in treeNode.cpp, but could you be a bit more clear with what you mean about template implementations needing to be in the header? Which header and in what file are you talking about? I did use template<class T> in my treeNode files

Comment: @user2137877 I added some more to the answer; see if it makes sense.